# Javascript 2D array generation doesn't work as intended

Tags: javascript, arrays, debugging

I am new here, and to programming as well. Anyway, to get in topic I wrote the following program with the purpose of generating a 2 dimensional array in JavaScript, and then displaying its elements in a table. However, in the place where the value of the `i` row array index was supposed to show (like `1` in first row, then `2` in the second row, etc), the number `10` shows instead. So, I'd appreciate if someone could explain what I did wrong. Here is the code:

```
<table border="1">
    <script>
        var array1 = [];
        var array2 = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                array2[j] = (i + 1) + "-" + (j + 1);
            }
            array1[i] = array2;
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            document.write("<tr>");
            for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                document.write("<td>" + array1[i][j] + "</td>");
            }
            document.write("</tr>");
        }
    </script>
</table>
```

Comment: Indent your code readably when asking for help, it's basic courtesy. I've done it for you on this occasion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding the same array to `array1`, again and again. Instead you need to create new arrays every time.

```
var array1 = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
    var array2 = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        array2[j] = (i+1) + "-" + (j+1);
    }
    array1[i]=array2;
}
```

But normally, this will be done with [`Array.prototype.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method, like this

```
var array1 = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
    var array2 = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        array2.push((i+1) + "-" + (j+1));
    }
    array1.push(array2);
}
```

Comment: Whether you use `push` or assign to the next slot is a style thing, some people do it one way (and some engines are faster that way), others do it the other (and some engines are faster *that* way). (Not that the speed is likely to matter here.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Agreed, but when we do `array2[j]`, sometimes people might find it difficult to understand that the array is getting extended. That is why I always prefer `push`.

Comment: Well thanks, it works just fine now. Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

You can create new array each time after assigned `array2` to `array1`, something like this

```
array2=[];
```

on

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        array2[j] = (i+1) + "-" + (j+1);

    }
    array1[i]=array2;
    array2=[]; //created new array each time after array2 assigned
}
```