# Javascript 2D array generation, "strange" behavior

Tags: javascript, arrays

So basically I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22281315/javascript-2d-array-generation-doesnt-work-as-intended) on the same topic earlier, and although I understand how and why the solutions in the answers work(which I appreciate), I cant wrap my head around as to the reason why my code doesn't work. So, the program is intended to generate a 2 dimensional array, which should replicate a multiplication table. However, the rows' values are repeated, instead of being appropriately different.

So basically, it produces 
    [ [3, 6, 9], 
      [3, 6, 9],
      [3, 6, 9] ] instead of the intended [ [1, 2, 3], 
      [2, 4, 6],
      [3, 6, 9] ]. What apparently happens is that, after the array "rows" (which correspond to arr2, assigned by the outerloop) are assigned, in the next repeat of the loop, not only the current element arr[j] is affected, but the preceeding elements too are changed/updated following the updated(changed) value of arr2, even though not (explicitly?) addressed and reassigned.

The alert statements demonstrate this, where same index elements have different values in different loops, even though they should be assigned once and not therefore changed after being assigned(at least to my knowledge, as they are assigned/indexed only once by the for loop). So why does this behavior happen in this case?

Code below:

```
<script>
    var arr = [];
    var arr2 =[];

    for (var j=0; j < 3; j++){
        for (var k=0; k<3; k++){
            arr2[k] = (k+1)*(j+1);
        }
        arr[j]=arr2;
        alert("arr[" + j + "]= " + arr[j]);
        alert("arr[" + (j-1) + "]= " + arr[j-1]);
    }

    alert("Finally: " + arr);
</script>
```

Comment: This will not produce the output you are describing. Your code produces: `Finally: 0,2,4,0,2,4,0,2,4`.

Comment: Also, the problem you're facing stems from the fact that you're using the same instance of an array stored in `arr2` and modifying it several times and assigning it to variables. What you actually want is to create a new array within each iteration of the `j` loop.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks, i fixed it. Got any idea for the question though?

Comment: Yes, see comment above. What you want is to have a statement at the beginning of the `j` loop saying `arr2 = []`.

Comment: Yeah, I know about that solution, but shouldnt the array be updated entirely and act as a new array? It changes back previous values, which i cant understand how.

Comment: Yes, the array is updated entirely. No, it won't act as a new array. You just end up overwriting all the values you assigned in the previous iteration.

Comment: Still, the value of previous arr[j] elements shouldnt be changed, as they are not assigned after the arr2 changes/is updated.

Comment: Yes they should be. The previous `arr[i]` elements *are* the array element stored in `arr2`. All three entries in `arr` are the same array, i.e. the array you have stored at the beginning of the script in `arr2`.

Comment: Oh well, I thought arr2 would be stored in arr[i], and not vice versa.

Comment: `arr2` is stored in `arr[0]`. And also in `arr[1]`. And in `arr[2]`. Or more accurately, by the end of the script, `arr2`, `arr[0]`, `arr[1]` and `arr[2]` all point to the same array (the one you assigned to `arr2` at the beginning of the script).

Answer (score 3):

You have declared `arr2` outside of your `for` loops with this line:

```
var arr2 = [];
```

That means every time you run this code:

```
for (var k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
  arr2[k] = (k + 1) * (j + 1);
}
```

...you are just replacing the values in the **same** instance of `arr2`.

This line:

```
arr[j] = arr2;
```

...is storing a *reference* to that one instance of `arr2`, *not a copy of it*. So every time you change `arr2`, every reference to it in `arr` changes as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
var arr = [], // the array to hold the answer
    arr2, // another variable for inner array, note reset in loop below
    j, // declaring this outside of loop for better style
    k;

for (j=0; j < 3; j++){
    arr2 = []; // clear inner array each time
    for (k=0; k < 3; k++){
        arr2[k] = (j + 1) * (k + 1); // build inner array
    }
    arr[j] = arr2; // add the inner array after building it.
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(arr)); // because console.log lets us see more detail than alert.

alert("Finally: " + arr);
```

Comment: Thank you, but what i dont understand: Why is "arr2 = []; // clear inner array each time"
 neccessary? The array is updated afer being assigned in each iteration, anyway.

Comment: `arr2 = [];` is a short way of writing `arr2 = new Array;` so we are insuring that later when we add arr2 into arr that we are adding a unique copy rather than a reference to a single instance.

Comment: @user3398216 Basically, when you have `var arr2 = []`, `arr2` does not actually contain the array, it contains a *reference* to that array in memory. When you do `arr[j] = arr2`, `arr[j]` now contains a reference to that *same array* in memory. Then when you do `arr2 = [];` as Jason Aller recommends, you are creating a *new array* in memory, and `arr2` is now referencing that instead. But the previous `arr[j]` still references the old array. Thus, you are not overwriting `arr2`, but creating new instances and storing references to them in `arr`.

Comment: Well, thanks all, now i understand. Glad i asked this, now i understand the assign concepts better.